# jQuery not working in laravel-mix (webpack)

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I can't get jQuery to work, i have required it in my app.js like this

```
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is undefined

Can someone help me? In `app.js` it works but if I import a other file and try to use jQuery there, it doesn't work

```
{
  "name": "art-factory",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.11",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-migrate": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');    
import './test';
```

test.js

```
console.log($('div'));
```

Comment: to be able to use jQuery in a browser you should use window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

Comment: I tried that to but that doesn't work either

Comment: have you recompiled with npm?

Comment: I use npm run watch

Comment: in app.js it works but if i import a other file and try to use jqeury there it doesn't work

Comment: please provide your package.json

Comment: Added the package.json in the question

Comment: package.json looks alright, which other file and its code that it does not work?

Comment: i have added the app.js and test.js in the question

Comment: it seems to be the problem with import, if you change to require('./test') it should work.

Comment: thanks this worked, but why does this work and import doesn't?

Comment: it may be because import is asynchronous but require is synchronous so with import your code is run before jQuery is loaded.